# I can't delete row after append it a foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two table `second` and `third`

```
second_id(PRIMARY KEY)  second_name           
   1                    .........
   2                    .......
   3                    .........

third_id(PRIMARY KEY) third_name second_id(FOREIGN KEY for second.second_id)
      1                  .....                 1
      2                  .....                 1
      3                  .....                 1
      4                  .....                 2
      5                  .....                 2
```

Now i want to delete a row from`second` where `second_id=2` (**`DELETE FROM second WHERE second_id=2`**) but it does not work. It says **`Successful 0 row(s) affected`** What is more is, it happened after i append a foreign key to `third.second_id` (i added foreign key after table is created).

Comment: You can set the Foreign Key ID to null in the third table and delete from the second table.

Comment: thank to all for helping me

Comment: @WebberDepor, remember to pick an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to delete the rows in `third` table with second_id = 2 and then delete the rows from `second` with id = 2 or have `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the foreign key constraint

Comment: i append a foreign key because i want  automaticly delete all `third.second_id` when `second.second_id` has been deleted. How can i do that?

Comment: when you add the foreign key constraint do this : ` FOREIGN KEY (`second_id`) REFERENCES `second`(`second_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete a row from `second` because one of it's values is being used in `third`. That's a Foreign Key rule.

But you can cascade the foreign key in a was that if you delete a row from `second`, all rows in `third` which uses this value will also be deleted, or you can set them to `null`.

[This manual from MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) can tell you how to properly use `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE`, and then you can pick up the best option for you.
Look up for Referential Actions

Edit:

You can't add ON DELETE CASCADE to an existing foreign key, so you will have to drop it first.

```
alter table third drop foreign key third_foreign
```

Then

```
alter table third add constraint third_foreign foreign key (second_id) references second(second_id) on delete cascade;
```

Comment: i append a foreign key because i want  automaticly delete all `third.second_id` when `second.second_id` has been deleted. How can i do that?

Comment: What is the name of your constraint ?