# Laravel SQL[23000] Delete error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

There are some problems with delete function on one table. I need a function that will handle the exception for foreign key constraints. 
Have to fix that function so I can add softdelete.
I tried to copy one column from that same table and when I deleted everything is good, but there are 2 columns that I can't delete. I will put delete function here.
If you need some more code from software please inform me, but I think this is all you need to know what is the problem.

> **Error massage**: pastebin.com/CktBbbaX (Can't post on the stack for some reason)

This is php function:

```
 public function destroy($id)
        {
            Rate::findOrFail($id)->delete();

            return redirect()->back()->with('status', __('messages/success.delete'));
        }
```

Rates table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('house_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->boolean('b4g_edit');
            $table->integer('derived_qty')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('derived_price')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('limit_quantity')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('round_prices', 10, 3);

            // TRANSLATABLE
            $table->integer('name_frontend')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('name_backend')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('description')->unsigned();
            // END TRANSLATABLE

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers')->onDelete('SET NULL');
            $table->foreign('house_id')->references('id')->on('houses')->onDelete('SET NULL');
            //translation foreign keys
            $table->foreign('name_frontend')->references('group_id')->on('translations')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('name_backend')->references('group_id')->on('translations')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('description')->references('group_id')->on('translations')->onDelete('CASCADE');         
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('rates');
    }
```

And this is rate-parts:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rate_parts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('rate_id')->unsigned();
            $table->enum(
                'product_type',
                [ 'overnight','transport','activity','addon' ]
            );
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->date('date_from');
            $table->date('date_to');
            $table->enum(
                'type',
                [
                    'dummy',
                    'quantity',
                    'price',
                    'closed',
                    'cta',
                    'ctd',
                    'minstay',
                    'start',
                    'expire',
                    'min',
                    'max',
                    'max_beds',
                    'persons',
                    'daily_price',
                    'km_price',
                    'pricechange_abs',
                    'pricechange_rel'
                ]
            );
            $table->decimal('value', 10, 2);

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->index(['product_id', 'product_type']);
            $table->foreign('rate_id')->references('id')->on('rates');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('rate_parts');
    }
```

Comment: It looks like it cannot delete since a foreign key to this row is being referenced from another table to the row you're trying to delete, are you deleting the foreign key row before deleting ?

Comment: Hi @Dinosan0908 thank's for understanding. No i don't delete any foreign key.  It must handle the exception for foreign key constraints, but how?

Answer (score 0):

if Table A has a column with Foreign Key referencing Table B ( for example Table_B_ID ), you can't delete Table B row that is referenced, because there is a dependency with the foreign Key. What you need to do is deleting the reference row pointing to the Table B row.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34501633/4925008

Check this answer from a similar problem to yours. You either need to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` or manually delete the row before deleting the main row you're trying to delete

Comment: Where to add that Delete Cascade?

Comment: Here's a how to https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/07139c566b-add-on-delete-cascade-to-foreign-key-constraint 

If you can't do that, then just manually delete the row that has the foreign key pointing to your row before deleting the main row

Comment: But why when i copy exact table, i can delete it. I just can't delete that 2 old columns.

Comment: So you have rows with FKs pointing to the rows you're trying to delete, but you can't delete these rows ? I'm not sure I get it, is there any reason you need to keep these rows ? If yes you have a design issue in your database

Comment: I have reason, this is not my software, but for company :) i must to handle somehow that request. I'm actually junior php developer, and i know how to add softdelete and fix problems like this. But the problem is when i make exact same copy, i can delete copy but i can't delete this 2 old rows. Nobody touch this table for maybe 1 year.